# How can a Qt app on linux crash and the stack has none of my code in it (only QT code and std libs)?

Tags: c++, linux, qt

My customers are running a C++/Qt app on Linux and I'm using google's breakpad for crash reporting.  On a bunch of occasions, I receive a stack trace like this that has only QT code in the stack (none of my code). How can this be?

```
Operating system: Linux
                  0.0.0 Linux 3.16.0-0.bpo.4-586 #1 Debian 3.16.7-ckt9-3~deb8u1~bpo70+1 (2015-04-27) i686
CPU: x86
     AuthenticAMD family 16 model 5 stepping 3
     1 CPU

Crash reason:  SIGABRT
Crash address: 0x939
Process uptime: not available
    Thread 11 (crashed)
     0  libc-2.13.so + 0x2a387
        eip = 0xb4940387   esp = 0xaf980008   ebp = 0xaf980010   ebx = 0x00000939
        esi = 0xb4b3cba2   edi = 0xb4a60ff4   eax = 0x00000000   ecx = 0x00000a1b
        edx = 0x00000006   efl = 0x00000206
        Found by: given as instruction pointer in context
     1  libc-2.13.so + 0x2d772
        eip = 0xb4943772   esp = 0xaf980018   ebp = 0xaf980138
        Found by: previous frame's frame pointer
     2  libstdc++.so.6.0.17 + 0x5128d
        eip = 0xb4ad328d   esp = 0xaf980140   ebp = 0xa0cf07b8
        Found by: previous frame's frame pointer
     3  libc-2.13.so + 0x14b560
        eip = 0xb4a61560   esp = 0xaf980148   ebp = 0xa0cf07b8
        Found by: stack scanning
     4  libc-2.13.so + 0x14b560
        eip = 0xb4a61560   esp = 0xaf980150   ebp = 0xa0cf07b8
        Found by: stack scanning
     5  ld-2.13.so + 0x1cff4
        eip = 0xb7734ff4   esp = 0xaf98015c   ebp = 0xa0cf07b8
        Found by: stack scanning
     6  ld-2.13.so + 0xdc16
        eip = 0xb7725c16   esp = 0xaf98016c   ebp = 0xaf9801a0
        Found by: stack scanning
     7  ld-2.13.so + 0x139c0
        eip = 0xb772b9c0   esp = 0xaf9801a8   ebp = 0xb4ad3140
        Found by: previous frame's frame pointer
     8  libstdc++.so.6.0.17 + 0x4ef10
        eip = 0xb4ad0f10   esp = 0xaf9801b0   ebp = 0xb4ad3140
        Found by: stack scanning
     9  libstdc++.so.6.0.17 + 0x4ef16
        eip = 0xb4ad0f16   esp = 0xaf9801b8   ebp = 0xb4ad3140
        Found by: stack scanning
    10  libstdc++.so.6.0.17 + 0xe3ff4
        eip = 0xb4b65ff4   esp = 0xaf9801bc   ebp = 0xb4ad3140
        Found by: stack scanning
    11  libstdc++.so.6.0.17 + 0x4f225
        eip = 0xb4ad1225   esp = 0xaf9801c0   ebp = 0xb4ad3140
        Found by: stack scanning
    12  libQtCore.so.4.8.6 + 0x196f05
        eip = 0xb4d1ef05   esp = 0xaf9801cc   ebp = 0xb4ad3140
        Found by: stack scanning
    13  libstdc++.so.6.0.17 + 0x4f1d8
        eip = 0xb4ad11d8   esp = 0xaf9801d0   ebp = 0xb4ad3140
        Found by: stack scanning
    14  libQtCore.so.4.8.6 + 0x2f0ff4
        eip = 0xb4e78ff4   esp = 0xaf9801d4   ebp = 0xb4ad3140
        Found by: stack scanning
    15  libQtCore.so.4.8.6 + 0x183417
        eip = 0xb4d0b417   esp = 0xaf9801e0   ebp = 0xb4ad3140
        Found by: stack scanning
    16  libQtCore.so.4.8.6 + 0x2f0ff4
        eip = 0xb4e78ff4   esp = 0xaf980220   ebp = 0xb4ad3140
        Found by: stack scanning
    17  libQtCore.so.4.8.6 + 0x6b07c
        eip = 0xb4bf307c   esp = 0xaf980230   ebp = 0xaf980258
        Found by: stack scanning
    18  0xdb78310
        eip = 0x0db78310   esp = 0xaf980260   ebp = 0xb4e782c8
        Found by: previous frame's frame pointer
    19  ld-2.13.so + 0x11066
        eip = 0xb7729066   esp = 0xaf980268   ebp = 0xb4e782c8
        Found by: stack scanning
    20  ld-2.13.so + 0x10d5e
        eip = 0xb7728d5e   esp = 0xaf98026c   ebp = 0xb4e782c8
        Found by: stack scanning
    21  libQtCore.so.4.8.6 + 0x2f0ff4
        eip = 0xb4e78ff4   esp = 0xaf980270   ebp = 0xb4e782c8
        Found by: stack scanning
    22  libQtCore.so.4.8.6 + 0x6b1db
        eip = 0xb4bf31db   esp = 0xaf980280   ebp = 0xb4e782c8
        Found by: stack scanning
    23  libQtCore.so.4.8.6 + 0x2ef890
        eip = 0xb4e77890   esp = 0xaf980288   ebp = 0xb4e782c8
        Found by: stack scanning
    24  libQtCore.so.4.8.6 + 0x2f0ff4
        eip = 0xb4e78ff4   esp = 0xaf98029c   ebp = 0xaf9802c8
        Found by: stack scanning
    25  libpthread-2.13.so + 0x584c
        eip = 0xb4b7384c   esp = 0xaf9802d0   ebp = 0x08181ee0
        Found by: previous frame's frame pointer
    26  libc-2.13.so + 0xa730
        eip = 0xb4920730   esp = 0xaf9802d4   ebp = 0x08181ee0
        Found by: stack scanning
    27  libpthread-2.13.so + 0x15ff4
        eip = 0xb4b83ff4   esp = 0xaf9802d8   ebp = 0x08181ee0
        Found by: stack scanning
    28  libQtCore.so.4.8.6 + 0x6e3b9
        eip = 0xb4bf63b9   esp = 0xaf9802dc   ebp = 0x08181ee0
        Found by: stack scanning
    29  libpthread-2.13.so + 0x15ff4
        eip = 0xb4b83ff4   esp = 0xaf9802e0   ebp = 0x08181ee0
        Found by: stack scanning
    30  libpthread-2.13.so + 0x5954
        eip = 0xb4b73954   esp = 0xaf9802f0   ebp = 0xaf9803e8
        Found by: stack scanning
    31  libc-2.13.so + 0xd5c8e
        eip = 0xb49ebc8e   esp = 0xaf9803f0   ebp = 0x00000000
        Found by: previous frame's frame pointer
```

Comment: Hard to tell, especially without the symbols. Could be a Qt bug, or your code doing something weird that then causes a crash later on inside Qt/libstdc++.

Comment: First, you have to get the symbol resolution working. This backtrace is not very useful otherwise. Secondly, the crash might happen sometime after the damage has been.

Answer (score 1):

"How can a Qt app on linux crash..."

Due to memory bugs in your code, for example. Remember that undefined behavior introduced by memory bugs means just that. It doesn't mean "it'll crash ASAP". It may crash yesterday, tomorrow, or a year later.